# Coalesce intersecting sets into disjoint sets

Tags: algorithm

I am looking for an algorithm to coalesce a list of sets, that may intersect, into a list of sets with no intersection.

For instance:

```
my_sets = set(1, 2, 3), set(5, 6), set(4, 5, 6), set(4, 7), set(3, 8), set(9)
```

Should yield:

```
my_coalesced_sets = set(1, 2, 3, 8), set(4, 5, 6, 7), set(9)
```

Ideally an algorithm O(n)...

At the request of Ruben, here is one of the many algorithms I tried that does not yield correct results:

```
fun main(){
    val l = mutableListOf(setOf(1, 2, 3), setOf(5, 6), setOf(4, 5, 6), setOf(4, 7), setOf(3, 8), setOf(9))
    while (true){
        val removes = mutableListOf<Set<Int>>()
        var current = l.removeFirst()
        l.filter { current.intersect(it).isNotEmpty() }.forEach {
            current = current union it
            removes += it
        }
        l += current
        if (removes.isEmpty()){
            break
        }
        l.removeAll(removes)
    }
    print(l)
}
```

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: @RubenHelsloot The OP was asking what algorithms were available. Finding or designing one would be a precondition for writing code.

Answer (score 1):

This is the purpose of the [disjoint-set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure). Simply add an edge ("Union") for each consecutive pair in each input set, and the result will be the coalesced sets. The running time is essentially linear (very slightly super-linear but that's only a theoretical difference).